USE command not working to select a database
I am using phpmyadmin to run MySQL code via XAMPP.
I run:
CREATE DATABASE d1;
And I see a database named 'd1' is created (visible on left side of my screen).
Now when I run:
USE d1;
I get the message that the code ran successfully but I get the output that No database is selected.
And then I run:
SELECT DATABASE ();
I get NULL in output and the same message that No database is selected, where as I was expecting it to output 'd1'.
Where am I going wrong?
Edit: The question is different from the associated duplicate because: I am not able to understand why database d1 is not getting selecting despite using the USE d1; command.

I don't think PhpMyAdmin uses the same MySQL connection for each query. Do this from the command-line client and it will work.

Permissions? Maybe you can create a DB bit ir your user able to see/use it?

@jean , when i manually select the created database 'd1' from the left menu. I am able to work on the database and upon executing the command, SELECT DATABASE(); , I also see 'd1' in output, so permission is not a problem. I am not able to understand why USE command doesn't work to select a database.

@ramank27, The USE command sets the default database for the current database session. Once that session ends, the default database is reset. But PHP naturally opens a new database session for each request. Executing USE in one request does not apply to subsequent requests.

@BillKarwin, thanks. I also find that when I execute the commands USE d1;  and SELECT DATABASE(); together (i.e. in one session), I see d1 in output, as expected. Is there any way to keep the session going?

No, PHP is called a "shared nothing" language, meaning no resources survive between requests. This is by design. If you don't like this behavior, then you must use a different client for MySQL.
